# Bootstrap хэдер не коллапсирует на узком экране, но должен

Tags: html, bootstrap

Создал фиксированный хэдер, по идее должен коллапсировать на узких экранах, вместо этого ничего не меняется, 2 фото так должно быть сам сайт - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVhyJ.jpg должен - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjKNZ.jpg выходит - https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0wza.png

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = 
  ".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: grey; font-size: 12pt;">
        <span style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 12pt;">Shumik_UA</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <? if ($_SESSION["is_logged"] == false) {
                 require("includes/login.html");
        }
         if ($_SESSION["is_logged"] == true) {
                 require("includes/islogged.html");
         }
        ?>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте воспроизводимый код хедера, из этого отрывка ничего не понятно

Comment: ощущение, что вы при переходе в эмулятор просто ctrl+r не нажимаете

Comment: упс, не тот код был, нечайно другой скопировал, теперь правильно

Comment: ну зачем вы обратно то откатили? делайте тогда сами фото видимыми, и код воспроизводимым

Comment: а что с фотками? я кинул просто ссылку фотографий и код

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/792152/revisions